# Uncaught TypeError. Click event handling for dynamically rendered html

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am building a two part html form for generating invoices and agreements.

HTML is rendered with switch button (checkbox). Checked renders invoice form (default), unchecked renders agreement form.

I have two function for getting each form input values.

`invoiceInputs()`

- works OK, because on initial page load invoice form is already in the DOM.

`agreementInputs()`

- is called conditionally (`!elements.switch.hasAttribute('checked')`). So the agreement markup is already in the DOM.
- gets Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null.
- `console.log` works fine function doesn't.

My guess is that it has something to do with agreement form not being in the DOM on initial page load.

Event delegation is not the case because Submit button is always on the page.

I have confirmed that `agreementInputs()` gets all values correctly.

Post your ideas in plain Javascript. Thanks.

```
/** AGREEMENT FORM CONTROLLER **/
const controlAgreementForm = () => {
  // Get input values from view
  const vals = agreementInputs();

  console.log(vals);
};


//Form submit
elements.downloadPDF.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!elements.switch.hasAttribute('checked')) {
    //console.log("work fine");
    controlAgreementForm(); // GETS Uncaught TypeError
  }
});


//Switch button - Load markup
elements.switch.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

    clearContainer(elements.invAgrContainer);

    if(elements.switch.hasAttribute('checked')) {
      elements.switch.removeAttribute("checked");
      agreementForm(); 
    } else if(!elements.switch.hasAttribute('checked')) {
      invoiceForm();
      elements.switch.setAttribute("checked", "");    
    }  
  });
```

In short, how to manipulate dynamically rendered DOM elements?

Comment: Use inspector and determine which line is causing the issue, in console you will see this error then just click on the js and it should lead you to the line where this error is caused

Comment: I have commented which line is causing a problem. It's a function call controlAgreementForm() that takes form input values.

Comment: That's not the line, go into the function call and see which actual line of code is producing the error and then you will know why it is not working. Most likely the error occurs in `agreementInputs()`